# Is there a way to count rows in databaframe based on column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a huge dataframe and I need to get for each row a count of rows after a column changed.
This is my dataframe:

```
       VALUE  SIGNAL
0      1       0
1      2       1
2      3       0
3      4       1
4      5       0
5      6       0
6      7       0
7      8       1
8      9       0
9     10       0
10    11       0
```

I need to calculate how many "0" are in SIGNAL each time when SIGNAL changes from "0" to "1". For example at index 3, the count should be 3 because on index 1 I have next SIGNAL = 1.

At index 7 my count should be 5, because previous change took place at index 3.

Also when I have a COUNT different than 0, I need to get the SUM of current row and previous row where SIGNAL switched from 0 to 1.

My final output will look like:

```
       VALUE  SIGNAL  COUNT   SUM   
0      1       0       0       0
1      2       1       0       0
2      3       0       0       0
3      4       1       3       6
4      5       0       0       0
5      6       0       0       0
6      7       0       0       0
7      8       1       5      12
8      9       0       0       0
9     10       0       0       0
10    11       0       0       0
```

My code:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['1', 0], ['2', 1], ['3', 0], ['4', 1], ['5', 0], ['6', 0], ['7', 0], ['8', 1], ['9', 0], ['10', 0], ['11', 0]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['VALUE', 'SIGNAL'])
 
# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

I can do this through iteration but I am afraid that the performance will be reduced. Is there a way to calculate both COUNT and SUM columns in a pan

**UPDATE:**

I applied the code from  mitoRibo with some small extra query and it works as expected:

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# initialize list of lists
data = [['1', 0], ['2', 1], ['3', 0], ['4', 1], ['5', 0], ['6', 0], ['7', 0], ['8', 1], ['9', 0], ['10', 0], ['11', 0]]
 
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['VALUE', 'SIGNAL'])


df['COUNT'] = np.cumsum(df['SIGNAL'] != df['SIGNAL'].shift(1))-1

my_query_index = df.query('SIGNAL != 1').index
df.loc[my_query_index,'COUNT'] = 0


# print dataframe.
print(df)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After I updated the code from production I noticed that in some case doesn't work good:

```
   VALUE  SIGNAL  COUNT
0      1       0      0
1      2       1      1
2      3       0      0
3      4       1      3
4      5       0      0
5      6       1      5 # <- this is wrong, previous "1" is at 3 rows above 
6      7       0      0
7      8       1      7 # <- this is wrong, previous "1" is at 3 rows above
8      9       0      0
9     10       0      0
10    11       0      0
```

Is like the COUNT should reset itself at 0 each time SIGNAL switch from 1 -> 0.

Comment: why is the count 0 at index 1?

Comment: something like `np.cumsum(df['SIGNAL'] != df['SIGNAL'].shift(1))-1`?

Comment: **Why is the COUNT 3 *(and not 2)* at index 3**, when there are only 2 zeros in SIGNAL before index 3?

Comment: The COUNT = 3 at index 3, because index 3 = 1, and index 1 = 1. This means that for index 3, the previous SIGNAL appeared 3 rows above (including current one).

Comment: @Mohammad the count is 0 at index 1 because above of index 1 there is no row where SIGNAL = 1

Comment: @mitoRibo thanks. Very smart solution. I dont understand it exactly but I have some basic idea. I had also to add a query to replace COUNT with 0 where SIGNAL = 0 because without this the COUNT will have values also when SIGNAL = 0. I will update my question with complete code.

Comment: *I need to calculate how many "0" are in SIGNAL each time when SIGNAL changes from "0" to "1"* - that's what I couldn't understand about `df.loc[1,'COUNT']` in the example showing as `0`.  The update and accepted code for the count column shows that should be `1`.

Comment: @MDR you are right, the code is returning COUNT  = 1 for index 1 but will not affect me so much because always in beginning of my dataframe the first row will have SIGNAL = 1. The table that I posted was just an example.

Comment: @mitoRibo any idea how i can use your code to calculate also the SUM column as being a SUM between df['VALUE'] of row where SIGNAL = 1 and the df['VALUE'] of row where SIGNAL previously switched from 0 to 1? 
For example on index 3 the sum is 6 = VALUE index 1 + VALUE index 3